# Placemark not giving zip code to find out weather information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation, clgeocoder

I want to find out the weather from the current location.

For that I used the code as

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    self.location = newLocation;
//    NSLog(@"lat long = %f,%f",self.location.coordinate.latitude,self.location.coordinate.longitude);

    // Geocode coordinate (normally we'd use location.coordinate here instead of coord).
    // This will get us something we can query Google's Weather API with

    if (boolCurrentlyWorking == NO) {

        CLGeocoder* reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        if(reverseGeocoder)
        {
            [reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                CLPlacemark* placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                if (placemark) {
                    //Using blocks, get zip code
                    NSString *zipCode = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
                    NSLog(@"placemark : %@ zipcode : %@",placemark.addressDictionary,zipCode);
                }
            }];

        }else{
            MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate];
            geocoder.delegate = self;
            [geocoder start];
        }
     }

    boolCurrentlyWorking = YES;
}
```

I am not getting zip code here.

Also found out that this method of didupdate location has been deprecated and new method is

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *newlocation = location;
    NSLog(@"location : %@",location);
    CLGeocoder* reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    if(reverseGeocoder)
    {
        [reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newlocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks)
            {
                NSLog(@"plcaemark desc : %@",[placemark description]);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

But it also does not contain zipcode.

I got this description

```
{
    Country = India;
    CountryCode = IN;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        NH8C,
        Gujarat,
        India
    );
    Name = NH8C;
    State = Gujarat;
    Street = NH8C;
    Thoroughfare = NH8C;
}
```

Is there like it does not provide zipcode information and we have to build it? If yes then how?

Comment: Have you tried simulating locations other than the one you have already? I tried myself, and I am not receiving postal codes for many places in India from the geocoder.

Comment: Yes zipcode or postal codes are not being available for India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all We are not getting any zip code or postal code for India.

Also Google API has been stop working.

I used yahoo api to find out weather.

Here is the code that might help someone

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    self.location = newLocation;



        NSString *linkForWoeid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=%f,%f&flags=J&gflags=R&appid=zHgnBS4m",self.location.coordinate.latitude,self.location.coordinate.longitude];
        NSURL *woeidURL = [NSURL URLWithString:linkForWoeid];
        NSData *WoeidData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:woeidURL];
        if (WoeidData != NULL)
        {
            NSError *woeiderr = nil;
            NSDictionary *aDicWOEIDResp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WoeidData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&woeiderr];
            NSDictionary *aDictWOEID = [[[[aDicWOEIDResp objectForKey:@"ResultSet"]objectForKey:@"Results"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"woeid"];

            NSString *address=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%@",aDictWOEID];
            ICB_WeatherConditions *icbWeather = [[ICB_WeatherConditions alloc] initWithQuery:address];

}

#import "ICB_WeatherConditions.m"

- (ICB_WeatherConditions *)initWithQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:query];
        CXMLDocument *parser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

        NSDictionary *namespaceMedia = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" forKey:@"yweather"];
        NSArray *nodes = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//channel" error:nil];

        for (CXMLNode *node in nodes) {
            if ([node kind] == CXMLElementKind)
            {
                CXMLElement *element = (CXMLElement *)node;
                for(int i=0;i<[element childCount];i++)
                {
                    NSString *strKey = [[element childAtIndex:i] name];
                    if([strKey isEqual:@"location"])
                    {
                        location = [self stringForXPath:@"@city" ofNode:[element childAtIndex:i] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia];
                    }
                    else if([strKey isEqual:@"item"])
                    {
                        NSArray *nodeItem = [element nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];
                        CXMLElement *elementItem = [nodeItem objectAtIndex:0];
                        for(int j=0;j<[elementItem childCount];j++){
                            NSString *strKeyItem = [[elementItem childAtIndex:j] name];
                            if([strKeyItem isEqual:@"condition"]){
                                condition =[self stringForXPath:@"@text" ofNode:[elementItem childAtIndex:j] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia];
                                currentTemp = [[self stringForXPath:@"@temp" ofNode:[elementItem childAtIndex:j] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia] intValue];
                            }
                            else if([strKeyItem isEqual:@"forecast"])
                            {
                                NSString *date = [self stringForXPath:@"@date" ofNode:[elementItem childAtIndex:j] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia];
                                NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
                                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy";
                                NSString *strCurDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:curDate];
                                if([date isEqual:strCurDate])
                                {
                                    highTemp = [[self stringForXPath:@"@high" ofNode:[elementItem childAtIndex:j] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia] intValue];
                                    lowTemp = [[self stringForXPath:@"@low" ofNode:[elementItem childAtIndex:j] withNameSpace:namespaceMedia] intValue];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }

            }
      }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is how I get the weather Details.
In my case I only needed Location,Condition,High Temp,Low Temp,Current Temp.